# I can't manage to integrate / modify code jssor slider

Tags: slider, jssor, integrate

I'm a beginner with jssor and I follow the tutorials: it's great, but I have 2 problems now . I'm blocked and I don't find the solution since many days...

1- I found an example in jssor.com. I exported the code and follow the process to integrate it in my website (jssor folder and copy/paste the code). I changed the pictures files but how to change texts (captions?) etc...? I am blocked!

2- So I created and saved a slider in my workspace in order to integrate it in my website. I downloaded my project but I only have myslider.slider and no code.txt or something else?
How can I do?

Thank you in advance for your help.
I precise you that I don't know code language. It's the reason why I find jssor very easy... if I manage to go further!

Regards,
D. Fabre

Answer (score 0):

View your slider https://www.jssor.com/[yourusername]/myslider.slider
And then click the command at top right corner of the slider, choose download 'standard code'.

For example, https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much for your answer....
It was so simple with your samples but very hidden for mine...
Have a nice day.

Regards,

Danielle